# get property of innerexception C#

Tags: c#, exception

I have created a custom exception class like the one below

```
public class FailedException : Exception
{
  private string failedtext;

  public FailedException(string message) : base(message)
  {
  }

  public FailedException(string message) : base(message, innerException)
  {
  }

  public string failedtext
  {
    get {return failedtext;}
    set {failedtext = value;}
  }
}
```

I am able to set the property failedtext when throwing the exception, but unable to get the failedtext in my main code; the exception comes as an innerexception, I can see the property but cannot get it. Is there a way to do this?

I want to get the value of failedtext to handle the error. Thanks.

Comment: How are you throwing this exception and how are you catching it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your main code looks like this:

```
try
{
  ThisWillThrow()
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  ex.InnerException.failedtext; //compile error on this line
}
```

The problem is that InnerException property is typed as Exception.  You can safely cast the object to your custom type by changing the catch block to:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
  FailedException fex = ex.InnerException as FailedException;
  if (fex != null)
  {
    string text = fex.failedtext;
  }
}
```

---

Also consider using the Data property of Exception instead of this custom type:

```
//thrower's code
Exception x = new Exception("my message");
x.Data["failedtext"] = "my failed text";

//catcher's code:
catch(Exception ex)
{
  if (ex.Data.Contains("failedtext") && ex.Data["failedtext"] is string)
  {
    string text = ex.Data["failedtext"];
  }
}
```

---

Also, your property is recursively defined.  Change it to this:

```
  public string failedtext
  {
    get;
    set;
  }
```

Comment: Regarding the last comment about the recursive property, I think OP is just showing us text code as it wouldn't even compile.